# How to rearrange 64-bit number into 8 8-bit numbers?

Tags: python

My program is supposed to take in a 64-bit number from a user input and sort them out into 8 8-bit numbers. For example, the 1st, 9th, 17th, 25th, 33rd, 41st, 49th, 57th number will be the first 8-bit number. The 2nd, 10th... and so on will be the second 8 bit number and so on until 8 8-bit numbers are generated.

```
binary = input("Enter ")
for i in range(0,8): 
    for x in range (0,7):
            if binary[i+(8*x)] == '0': 
                print("0",end="")
            else:
                print("1",end="")
    print("\n")
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Python integers are variable-length, so it's unclear how force the user to enter a value that would require a specific number of bits.

Comment: When you say "1st, 9th, ... number" do you mean bits?

Comment: Is the user entering the number as a binary string?

Comment: Why is the inner loop only `range(0, 7)` instead of `range(0, 8)`? You're skipping a bit every time.

Comment: @Barmar Also, `range(0, N)` can be replaced with just `range(N)`

Comment: "Can someone tell me what's wrong?" You haven't explained the problem you're having, so how can we tell you what's wrong?

Comment: You probably want to have a look at the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html?highlight=struct) in the Python standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import choices

bits = "".join(choices(["0", "1"], k=64))
numbers = [bits[i::8] for i in range(8)]
print(numbers)
```

First, I generate a string of length 64, containing only ones and zeroes. You don't need to do this step since you get your number from the user.

The meat and potatoes of the program is on the next line, which is a cute list-comprehension. It generates eight strings, each of which is a sliced substring of the original bits string. The slicing operation `bits[i::8]` starts the current slice from index i, and has a step size of eight (jumping over eight characters at a time, starting at i).